# How can I return response from service controller?

Tags: symfony, service, controller

I have a controller using like service and I need to return an array response to the main controller.
I don't know how to do it...

**My service.yml:**

```
parameters:
    check.usuari.class: Acme\UsuariBundle\Controller\CheckUserController

services:
    usuari:
        class: Acme\UsuariBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    check.usuari:
        class: "%check.usuari.class%"
```

**My controller (service):**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UsuariBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use Acme\UsuariBundle\Entity\Usuari;

class CheckUserController
{

    public function isUserLoggedInAction(Request $request){
        $sessio = $request->getSession()->get('gesaudit');
        if(!$sessio){
            return new JsonResponse(array('error'=>true));
        }

    }


}
```

**My main controller:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\IniciBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;

use Acme\IniciBundle\Entity\FraseSabiesque;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(){


        $asd = $this->forward('check.usuari:isUserLoggedInAction');
   }
}
?>
```

$asd variable doesn't show the array.
I need to get array to show a view or another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did it!

To return the information from service to controller this is the correct method:

```
 $response = new JsonResponse();
            $response->setData(array(
                'error'=>true,
                'url'=>'user_login',
            ));

            return $response;
```

To get it in the controller now I use:

```
$checkUser = $this->forward('check.usuari:isUserLoggedInAction');
        $checkUser = json_decode($checkUser->getContent());
        if($checkUser->error){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($checkUser->url));
        }
```

Thanks everyone!